# Al usar include para menu principal en varias paginas se mueven los enlaces

Tags: php, html, bootstrap, url

bueno resumiendo mi problema, tengo un sitio web en el cual tengo un menu de bootstrap y varias páginas, para ordenar las páginas las guarde en diferentes carpetas, el menú se encuentra en la raíz junto al index, al incluir dicho menú en alguna página dentro de una carpeta y dar click a alguno de los enlaces toma la dirección de la carpeta como parte de la url y no encuentra la página de destino, es decir, si la url en el enlace del menú es `/carpeta1/archivo.php` y me encuentro en `/carpeta2/archivo2.php` al dar click en el enlace que tiene el primer archivo en realidad me envía a `/carpeta2/carpeta1/archivo.php` sin resultado porque ahí no se encuentra ese archivo, quisiera saber si existe alguna forma de que el include tome los enlaces en el menú sin interponer la carpeta actual o es necesario siempre que todos los html que usen el menú se encuentren en la misma carpeta?

asi incluyo el menu al inicio de mi html:

```
<?php
include("../menu_pagina.phtml");
CabeceraPagina();
?>
```

un fragmento de codigo del menu:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu sub-menu">
 <li><a href="CEDIS/autoform_tkt_caja_cedis.php">Capturar tickets sin OC</a></li>
</ul>
```

si yo me encuentro en:

```
/IEMPAQUE/autoform_capt_caja_inspempc.php
```

y doy click en el enlacen del menu que me debe mandar a CEDIS, en vez de salir de la carpeta actual busca la carpeta CEDIS dentro de la carpeta IEMPAQUE... se puede solucionar o necesariamente debo tener todos los archivos que incluyen al menú en la carpeta raíz?

Comment: Será de utilidad pongas el código que te genera eso que indicas. Si las rutas siempre son desde raíz del sitio; prueba poniendo "/" al inicio de cada URL que indicas.

Comment: disculpame soy nuevo por aqui y no se si me explico bien, ya añadi un poco de código espero puedan ayudarme. muchas gracias

Comment: Le estás indicando una ruta relativa, prueba con `<li><a href="/CEDIS/autoform_tkt_caja_cedis.php">Capturar tickets sin OC</a></li>`
El detalle es la barra inclinada entes de CEDIS.

Comment: por Dios... haha me siento como un tonto es cierto lo que dices y batalle mucho tiempo por algo tan simple... muchisimas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

En efecto aplique la respuesta en el comentario de Roger Torné quedo asi:

```
<li><a href="/CEDIS/autoform_tkt_caja_cedis.php">Capturar tickets sin OC</a></li>
```

Gracias por su valioso apoyo!